# Transform rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, concatenation

I have a table with several rows per item number i.e.

```
Itemno  Component  Fabric     Fabric %
------  ---------  ------     --------
1       Back       Cotton     100
1       Face       Viscose    67
1       Face       Nylon      27
1       Face       Elastane   6
2       Main       Cotton     100
3       Back       Nylon      50
3       Back       Viscose    50
3       Face       Cotton     100
```

I want to transform this into one row per item number, concatenating the component, fabric & fabric % columns into one new column.  This would be easy using PIVOT, however the added complication is I don't want to repeat the component column if two are the same.

EDIT - forgot to mention, when there are multiple fabrics, I want them ordered descending from the largest to smallest.

Using the above example, the output I want is:

```
Itemno  Composition
------  -----------
1       Back 100% Cotton, Face 67% Viscose, 27% Nylon, 6% Elastane
2       Main 100% Cotton
3       Back 50% Nylon, 50% Viscose, Face 100% Cotton
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT - I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012!

Comment: I would assume you are using STUFF to generate the delimited list? Just skip the component in that part and concatenate the Component to the front of the delimited list.

Comment: You need combination of **listagg(..)** function

Comment: @Frank this is tagged with sql server, listagg is for Oracle if I remember correctly.

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't make it clear, yes this is Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using STUFF to generate a delimited list you will just need to create an intermediate list first of the distinct components.

Something like this should work for you.

```
DECLARE @Something TABLE
(
    ItemNo INT
    , Component VARCHAR(10)
    , Fabric VARCHAR(20)
    , FabricPercent INT
)

INSERT @Something
(
    ItemNo,
    Component,
    Fabric,
    FabricPercent
)
VALUES
(1, 'Back', 'Cotton', 100),
(1, 'Face', 'Viscose', 67),
(1, 'Face', 'Nylon', 27),
(1, 'Face', 'Elastane', 6),
(2, 'Main', 'Cotton', 100),
(3, 'Back', 'Nylon', 50),
(3, 'Back', 'Viscose', 50),
(3, 'Face', 'Cotton', 100 )
;

WITH GroupedComponents AS
(
    SELECT s.ItemNo
        , s.Component + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), s2.FabricPercent) + '% ' + s2.Fabric
                FROM @Something s2
                WHERE s2.ItemNo = s.ItemNo
                    AND s2.Component = s.Component
                ORDER BY s2.FabricPercent DESC
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Composition
    FROM @Something s
    GROUP BY s.ItemNo, s.Component
)

SELECT gc.ItemNo
    , STUFF((SELECT ', ' + gc2.Composition
            FROM GroupedComponents gc2
            WHERE gc2.ItemNo = gc.ItemNo
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'') AS FullComposition
FROM GroupedComponents gc
GROUP BY gc.ItemNo
```

Comment: If this works you should consider marking this as the answer. Glad to hear it is doing what you want.